# Android jitpack wont build from my repo

Tags: android, github, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I am trying to use a fork of a library using gradle and jitpack. I have the jitpack.io repositories setup (and working with another fork of another library).

The new fork I'm trying to include is the following : https://github.com/philippeauriach/ChatKit/tree/allow-moving-item

The jitpack website sees it well : https://jitpack.io/#philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT

But when I add `compile 'com.github.philippeauriach:ChatKit:allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT'` to my gradle dependency file, it says

```
12:03   Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.github.philippeauriach:ChatKit:allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.
            Required by:
            project :app
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

By using `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` I get the following logs :

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://maven.google.com/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://maven.google.com/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://maven.google.com/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jitpack.io/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-f906bb2db7-1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://jitpack.io/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/allow-moving-item-SNAPSHOT/ChatKit-allow-moving-item-f906bb2db7-1.jar]
```

Which means that jitpack does not have a module. Where could this come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
Checking the jitpack build log gave me more info about the problem : https://jitpack.io/com/github/philippeauriach/ChatKit/jitpack-compile-a17dd57690-1/build.log
(jitpack log url is https://jitpack.io/com/github/USER/REPO/TAG/build.log)

I was missing some files (and especially the wrapper jar file, needed by jitpack as stated [here](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/) : `Check that you have the Gradle wrapper in your Git repository. If you don’t then create it using the command gradle wrapper and commit it. Also check that the generated gradle-wrapper.jar is not ignored with .gitignore rules.` )

so running `gradle wrapper` at the root of my project generated those files :

```
gradlew
gradlew.bat
gradle/
    wrapper/
        gradle-wrapper.jar
        gradle-wrapper.properties
```

They need to be committed in order to use jitpack.